# Vuejs: can't make a composable universal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, composable

I need to make a composable universal.

Here's my case, I have 3 components - `ItemSwiper`, `ItemCard` and `ViewRecipeDetail`.

`ItemSwiper` contains card slides and it is the parent of `ItemCard`.

`ItemSwiper` has a loop of recipes:

```js
<Slide v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.data" :key="recipe.recipe_id">
       <ItemCard :data="recipe"/>
</Slide>
```

Here I'm passing the data prop to `ItemCard`.

Then, in the `ItemCard` I use this prop to display the information:

```html
<template>
    // here I'll add a skeleton loader that will be shown when the image is loading.
    <img class="card__image" :src="getSrc('.jpg')" :alt="data.alt" />
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

const isLoaded = ref(false);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/content/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};

onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
    img.onload = () => {
        isLoaded.value = true;
    };
    img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
});
</script>
```

I need to use this `getSrc` function and image preload in the `onMounted` hook in another component - `ViewRecipeDetail`, which isn't related to these two. In `ViewRecipeDetail` will be displayed the detailed information about a recipe.

I was thinking of moving this function and a hook into composable `useRecipe` and then use this composable in `ItemCard` and in `ViewRecipeDetail`.

However, due to the fact that in `ItemSwiper` I pass the `data` prop, which has `recipe` as its value, i.e. recipe in a loop, if I pass this prop as a parameter like this:

```js
import { useRecipe } from '@/composable/useRecipe';

const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

const { isLoaded, getSrc } = useRecipe(props.data);
```

Then in `useRecipe` we can use it like this:

```js
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

export function useRecipe(data) {
    const isLoaded = ref(false);
    const getSrc = ext => {
        return new URL(
            `../assets/images/content/recipe/${data.image}${ext}`,
            import.meta.url
        ).href;
    };

    onMounted(() => {
        const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
        img.onload = () => {
            isLoaded.value = true;
        };
        img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
    });

    return {
        isLoaded,
        getSrc,
    };
}
```

This will work for `ItemCard`, but it won't work for `ViewRecipeDetail`. Because I don't need any loop in `ViewRecipeDetail`. All I need to do is go to that recipe detail page and see the relevant information for that particular recipe.

It turns out that `useRecipe` is not universal now. We pass `props.data` as a parameter and it works for `ItemCard`, but it won't work for `ViewRecipeDetail`, because we need `storeRecipe.data` instead of `props.data`.

And here's `ViewRecipeDatail`. Please, tell me if I'm doing something wrong. I want to display an image same as I did in `ItemCard`, using a composable, but without a prop:

```
<template>
    <img
        class="card__image"
        :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
        :alt="storeRecipe.data.alt" />

    <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="card__title">
            {{ storeRecipe.data.title }}
        </h2>
        <p class="card__text">
            {{ storeRecipe.data.short_description }}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
import { useRecipe } from '@/composable/useRecipe';

const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

const { getSrc } = useRecipe(storeRecipe.data);
</script>
```

Please, give me a possible solution. (If you don't understand something, please, let me know).

Comment: not sure about the relevance of `Because I don't need any loop in ViewRecipeDetail` ... what does the loop have to do with anything, since useRecipe takes a single argument, regardless where that data comes from, as long as it's the correct data, who cares if there's some loop involved or not

Comment: Also you didn't show ViewRecipeDetail, it remains unclear why useRecipe won't work for it

Comment: @EstusFlask Update: I added `ViewRecipeDetail`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I don't know. All I want is to be able to use the composable in two not related components, but I don't understand how do it in my situation where I have props in one case and I don't have them in the second.

Comment: @JaromandaX what could you recommend instead of using a composable in my case?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/quirky-resonance-y5q5vv) - I've commented out the code regarding loading images, and added a random timeout instead - but, I think this may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent too much time on this :p but I wanted to see if composable was possible for what you want to do

There are a few changes to the composable, it returns a `src` and `isLoaded` (though, that's a bit redundant as `src` is `null` and `isLoaded` is `false` until the image loads, at which point `src` has the href, and `isLoaded` becomes true - you can see the redunancy there.

Anyway

The composable, `useRecipe.js`

```
import { ref, toValue, watchEffect } from "vue";

export function useRecipe(data, ext) {
  const isLoaded = ref(false);
  const src = ref(null);

  const getSrc = () => {
    isLoaded.value = false;
    const imgvalue = toValue(data)?.image;
    if (imgvalue) {
      const url = new URL(`../assets/images/content/recipe/${imgvalue}${ext}`, import.meta.url).href;
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        src.value = url;
        isLoaded.value = true;
      };
      img.src = url;
    }
  };

  watchEffect(() => {
    getSrc();
  });
  return {
    isLoaded,
    src,
  };
}
```

`ItemCard.vue` - changed for the alternative I propose

```
<script setup>
import { useRecipe } from "@/composables/useRecipe";
const props = defineProps(["data"]);
const { src, isLoaded } = useRecipe(props.data, ".jpg");
</script>
<template>
  <img class="card__image" :src="src" :alt="data.alt" />
</template>
```

`ItemSwiper.vue` - unchanged

`ViewRecipeDetail.vue` - I'm assuming `storeRecipe.data` here is NOT an Array, and not the same as `storeRecipe.data` in `ItemSwiper.vue`, since you don't treat it like an array in your code! Also, your description suggests this is a single recipe. Not sure why the variable name is the same as in ItemSwiper though.

```
<script setup>
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
import { useRecipe } from "@/composables/useRecipe";
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();
const { src, isLoaded } = useRecipe(storeRecipe.data, ".jpg");
</script>

<template>
  <img class="card__image" :src="src" :alt="data.alt" />
  <div class="card__content">
    <h2 class="card__title">
        {{ storeRecipe.data.title }}
    </h2>
    <p class="card__text">
        {{ storeRecipe.data.short_description }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!  `storeRecipe.data` is the same as in `ItemSwiper.vue`, because I grab the same data from the store and use it in different places. In `ItemSwier.vue` where `v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.data"` I loop through recipes by id. And then I pass a prop `data` to the `ItemCard`.

Comment: So you think this is the best way to do it, or maybe there's an easier way without composables involved? If you have any idea and you'd also like to try, I created another question for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578931/vuejs-how-to-pass-data-to-a-non-related-component. I'm trying to implement your version with the composable right now though.

Comment: no, I don't know if this is the best way @Michael - but a) it works, and b) it's simple