# How to pass data to an unrelated component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, store, pinia

I need to display an image, title and text for the particular recipe that I clicked on.

I have ItemSwiper (parent):

```js
<template>
     <Slide
         v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.data"
         :key="recipe.recipe_id">
         <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
     </Slide>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
import ItemCard from '@/component/ItemCard.vue';

// Pinia store
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadRecipes();
});
</script>
```

Then in ItemCard (child):

```js
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__item">
            <img
                class="card__image"
                :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
                :alt="data.alt"/>
            <div class="card__content">
                <h2 class="card__title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                <p class="card__text">{{ data.short_description }}</p>
                <router-link
                    class="card__link"
                    :to="{
                        name: 'recipeDetail',
                        params: { recipe: data.slug },
                    }"
                    >View more</router-link
                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

const isLoaded = ref(false);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/content/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};

onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
    img.onload = () => {
        isLoaded.value = true;
    };
    img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
});
</script>
```

And when I click on this 'View More' router-link, I go to the recipe detail page (`ViewRecipeDetail`):

```js
<template>
    <img
        class="card__image"
        :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
        :alt="storeRecipe.data.alt" />

    <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="card__title">
            {{ storeRecipe.data.title }}
        </h2>
        <p class="card__text">
            {{ storeRecipe.data.short_description }}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();
</script>
```

I want to be able to see the same image, title and other data in `ViewRecipeDetail` that was on the card in `ItemCard`. I don't understand how to do so, if `ViewRecipeDetail` is not related to `ItemCard`. All `ItemCard` has is just a router-link to this component. Also, I need to get access to `getSrc` in `ViewRecipeDetail` somehow as well without duplicating the code. Using a composable seems quite difficult.

`UPDATE` I added a store action and state:

action

```
export const actions = {
    async loadRecipes(keyword) {
        try {
            this.pending = true;
            keyword ??= '';
            const res = await fetch(
                `/api/recipe?keyword=${encodeURIComponent(keyword)}`
            );
            if (res.ok) {
                const data = await res.json();
                this.data = data;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', err);
            this.error = 'Failed to fetch data';
        } finally {
            this.pending = false;
        }
    },
};
```

state

```
export const state = () => {
    return {
        data: [],
        pending: false,
    };
};
```

Please, give me a possible solution. If there's any way to just use store, without query params on router-link, it would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. Since you are already using Pinia you can create a shared state that can be accessed by both 'ItemCard' and 'ViewRecipeDetail'.

Create an action to set the selectedRecipe data:

```
// storeRecipe.js

export const state = () => ({
    data: [],
    pending: false,
    selectedRecipe: null,
});

export const actions = {
    async loadRecipes(keyword) {
        try {
            this.pending = true;
            keyword ??= '';
            const res = await fetch(
                `/api/recipe?keyword=${encodeURIComponent(keyword)}`
            );
            if (res.ok) {
                const data = await res.json();
                this.data = data;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', err);
            this.error = 'Failed to fetch data';
        } finally {
            this.pending = false;
        }
    },

    selectRecipe(recipe) {
        this.selectedRecipe = recipe;
    },
};
```

Dispatch the action to set the selected recipe when router-link is clicked:

```
// ItemCard.vue

<router-link
    class="card__link"
    :to="{ name: 'recipeDetail' }"
    @click="handleClick"
>
    View more
</router-link>

<script setup>
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

const handleClick = () => {
    storeRecipe.selectRecipe(props.data);
};
</script>
```

Retrieve the selected recipe from the store:

```
// ViewRecipeDetail.vue

<template>
    <div v-if="storeRecipe.selectedRecipe">
        <img
            class="card__image"
            :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
            :alt="storeRecipe.selectedRecipe.alt"
        />

        <div class="card__content">
            <h2 class="card__title">
                {{ storeRecipe.selectedRecipe.title }}
            </h2>
            <p class="card__text">
                {{ storeRecipe.selectedRecipe.short_description }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();
</script>
```

Comment: I already had a store, I just updated my question, please look. Maybe it helps as well.

Comment: @Michael okay I already update the answer too, let me know if it works as u expected or not

Comment: It worked! But, there are a few issues:

1) If I go to another route `/searchRecipes`, where I have a search bar and I can type there name of the same recipe, it triggers `@input="loadRecipes"` event and if I click on the suggestion, content disappears, but I can see the correct URL. Should I add `storeRecipe.selectedRecipe` there as well (I tried, but didnt't work)?  Rn I have:
`
<li
   v-for="result in storeRecipe.data">
</li>
`
2) `getSrc` didn't work. I have all the data loaded, but the image isn't. (You probably missed that part, because I can't see it mentioned in your answer).

Comment: Update: `getSrc` worked when I copied this function from `ItemCard` to `ViewRecipeDetail`, but changed the string to "`../assets/images/content/recipe/${storeRecipe.selectedRecipe.image}${ext}`,". But should I copy it, or maybe I should have this function in my actions? How do I make it re-usable? Because I'll need to show the image in other components as well. Also, If you need more information about case 1), please, let me know. I could try to reproduce as well.

Comment: Also, if I click on the recipe from `ItemCard` and then refresh the page, the content disappears as well. It feels like it refreshes the `selectedRecipe` and it doesn't contain selected recipe data anymore.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I forgot to tell you that you should refactor the getSrc() function, because it used globally and by multiple components. You can move the getSrc() to helper, utils, or maybe mixin.

Comment: About the data disappears when page reloaded, you can store the selected recipe to localStorage or you can use some package/plugin to make data in your pinia is persist. I have some reference for that: https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/refresh-proof-your-pinia-stores and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=059fh7Gobho

Comment: if I move `getSrc()` to helper, how do I make it universal? In ItemCard I need `${props.data.image}` and in `ViewRecipeDetail` I need `${storeRecipe.selectedRecipe.image}`. About the `ViewSearchRecipe` where I search for recipes. When I find a recipe I click on it and go to the `ViewRecipeDetail`, same as I did from `ItemCard`. Problem is, if I click on recipe detail from ItemCard I see details, but if I go to `/searchRecipe` and find other recipe, it shows me the one that I opened from ItemCard, like it was cached. And if I reload, content disappears. Feels like something interferes.

Comment: You can visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613061/vue-js-making-helper-functions-globally-available-to-single-file-components

Comment: And maybe you can create action to clear/reset the `selectedRecipe` data when you change or move to different route, or maybe you can call the action on beforeDestroy in ViewRecipeDetail Component

Comment: okay thank you for the advice.

Comment: the problem with `beforeDestroy` (which is basically `onBeforeUnmount` in Vue 3) in this case, is that if I clear the `selectedRecipe` and let's say I want to return back to the previous route, I won't see the recipe and it's going to look like a bug.